# Removing all rows that are not a number in a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to remove all rows that are not a number in the column `['a','b']`. I have tried this but my approach does not work very well.

Dataframe

```py
        a   b  c
0     0.1  10  x
1     0.5   5  y
2  10 / 5  60  z
3     9.0  12  w
4     125   a  w
```

Code

```py
import uuid
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [0.1,0.5,'10 / 5', 9.0, 125],
     'b': [10, 5, 60, 12, 'a'],
     'c': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'w']
    })

print(df)
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda x: uuid.uuid4().int, axis=1)
df_ = df[['a', 'b', 'id']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).dropna()
df.merge(df_, left_on=['id'], right_on=['id'], how='inner')
```

What I want

```py
        a   b  c
0     0.1  10  x
1     0.5   5  y
3     9.0  12  w
```

Comment: That's a very convoluted way (adding a unique ID, then joining with the converted table, with id,...) to do it. You already got an answer showing how to do it way more simply. But the main reason why your method fails, is because you converted your ID to numeric, and since they are big ID, rounding make them different from the original one.

Comment: If for your id column you had done ``df[id]=range(len(df))`` for example, then no rounding, and your method works (with, I am pretty sure, some ``a_x`` and ``a_y`` columns that were not intended, but that is some tuning to do on your join, and at least it is not an empty table, and it has the rows you wanted). Still a bad idea. But it works. To be clear, I'm explaining why you have an empty table, not telling you how it must be done. How it must be done is what BENY told you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
out = df[~df[['a', 'b', 'id']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).isna().any(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

what about that

```
new_df = df[list(df.a.str.isnumeric() != False) and list(df.a.str.isnumeric() != False)]


    a   b   c
0   0.1 10  x
1   0.5 5   y
3   9.0 12  w
4   125 a   w
```

I am sure there is a nicer version doing this, but isnumeric() doesn't work as expected (by my)